# Expression on a highly anticipated event, but there is a 50/50 chance that it might not actually happen

Tags: expressions

Is there an expression in English to describe an event that is highly anticipated (like a plan that someone has worked on for a long time to make happen and everyone around anticipates good results) but there is 50/50 that the hard work might not actually pay off?

Thank you!

Comment: "Fingers crossed"

Comment: What is the Sentence you want to use that Expression in ?

Comment: No 50/50 sense here, but when this happens, we are *on pins and needles* — in an agitated state of suspense...

Answer (score 2):

One expression is

> **It's in the lap of the gods.**
>
> Beyond one's control, in the hands of providence. For example, *She's done what she can to expedite matters; now it's in the lap of the gods.*

From [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lap+of+the+gods%2c+in+the).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can find an expression which means anticipation and bears the fifty-fifty chance connotation as well.

You can use ***toss-up*** with a verb that expresses anticipation. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/toss-up) says

> If you describe a situation as a toss-up, you mean that either of two possibilities is equally likely:
>
> - It was ***a toss-up*** who would win, right to the end of the game.

[OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=tossup%20meaning&oq=tossup&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512l9.5134j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) labels it informal and spells it in one word:

> a situation in which any of two or more outcomes or options is equally possible or equally attractive.
>
> - In the end it was a toss-up between the mussels, the crispy prawn parcels, and the smoked trout.

Comment: 'Toss-up' is a good find, but Oxford's dubious example would need a three-sided coin :)

Comment: Well, not if you toss-up by pairs I guess :))